# ids for this class must bee manually assigned?

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently changed my form fields in my html. And changed abit in my servlet as per requesting parameters. I did not change anything in my mysql database or user class, or any other hibernate specifications. And now I'm suddenly getting this error?

I'm thinking it has something to do with my @Id being a string? But this worked fine for me before these changes. So It seems odd to me why it'll suddenly begin bugging me since I have not changed any hibernate relevant.

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.Tooblo.User
    org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:34)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:747)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:752)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:338)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.persist(Unknown Source)
    com.Tooblo.DAOImplements.persist(DAOImplements.java:18)
    com.Tooblo.eventHandler.createProfileIndividual(eventHandler.java:226)
    com.Tooblo.eventHandler.doGet(eventHandler.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My user class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {


    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long empId;

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String organisation;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }  )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_marker",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "marker_id")})
    private Set<Marker> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

...Setters and getters ormitted.

my servlet method.

```
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        User user = new User(username, password, email);

        DAO.persist(user);
```

And my persist method in my DAO

```
@Override
    public void persist(Object entity) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();    
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: @Id means that this is an identifiant. In your class the Id is the username and not the empId. Move the Id annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mysql server, it doesn't support **AUTO_INCREMENT** for a **non-primary key** attribute and your primary key is **username**.

so you can change primary key to **empId** field in your Entity class as well as in your DB Schema.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
private long empId;
```